# How to include bootstrap codes in spring MVC?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc

I have a `Spring-MVC` project in which I have included downloaded bootstrap codes for the frontend part. The project was working fine and then my laptop crashed. I had to reinstall my OS and eclipse and everything. I managed to gather all the files of my project but I have a problem with the bootstrap part.

The project has an `index.jsp` file inside web app folder. When I run the project, it displays "hello world" in the browser (the code from this index.jsp file).

In the same web app folder, I have pasted the downloaded codes of bootstrap, which consists a folder "view" with files index.html and form.html, along with other separate folders for CSS, fonts, js etc.

Previously, before my laptop crashed, I was able to run the index.html and form.html files inside the view folder which displayed a dashboard in the browser. Now, these things do not work at all. I think some code was added to the XML files to allow the spring framework find these files, but I cannot remember exactly what. I searched for it on google but could not find anything useful.
So, my question is, what do I need to do to make the bootstrap codes run in my project?

Thanks for your time.

[Structure of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENRmh.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring-MVC has provided facility to point to the location of resources with a specific public URL pattern. If you are using the xml based configuration, you can add the mvc tag which takes the location of resources,

```
<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources 
    directory -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

Add above entry in your application servlet xml. Here, `resources` folder will be looked up for any resource files like CSS, JS, or images.

With above declaration in xml, you can use any resources in your HTML pages like below,

```
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/myCss.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want to use the different location of resources you can provide that, but I would recommend adding `resources` folder in webapp folder. Then, add your bootstrap resources in `resources` folder.

Comment: Yes I am using xml based configuration, but where do I add those lines? Since my resource files are inside webapp folder, do I replace resources with webapp? I am sorry but I am new to spring framework and I would appreciate a more elaborate answer. Thanks.

Comment: @dhakalkumar check updated answer, let me know if you need any help.